# Xcode: How to make UIObject hide on a specific weekday?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

How can I make an UIObject like UITextField hide on a weekday, like Sunday, for example?

Comment: What is a UIObject And how will an IDE hier it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` or in a similar method:

```
static const WeekdaySunday = 1;                    // 1
NSCalendar *curCal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // 2
NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];                   // 3

textField.hidden = [curCal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit  // 4
                             fromDate:curDate].weekday != WeekdaySunday;
```

1. A sunday is represented as **one** (monday as two, ..., saturday as seven)
2. Get the current calendar, or use a calendar created in a different way
3. Get the current date
4. Get the weekday from the current date interpreted against the calendar (it returns `NSDateComponents *`) and compare the `weekday` with your day it should be hidden (the comparison has to be negated)

Comment: If this answer satisfied you, please click the check mark to the left of the answer.